# Accessing struct pointer as pthread arg causes seg fault?

Tags: c, arguments, pthreads

So here is a small portion of my code. Essentially I am starting another thread from a method, but when I pass the integer to the pthread, I can't access the struct members like I could only two lines before I called the thread. What has occurred since I passed this argument and run a new thread?

Note that without fail, my program always crashes immediately after *printf("1\n");*, I discovered this error when I realised FD_ZERO didn't work.

**Struct definition (in global area):**

```
typedef struct {
        fd_set read_set, write_set;
        unsigned int room_id;
        char room_name[16];
} room;
```

**Caller method:**

```
void create_new_room(int cli_index, char buffer[]) {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        char room_name[16], password[16];
        int capacity, r_index;

        room *new_room = malloc(sizeof(room));

        pthread_t tid;

        FILE *room_file = NULL;

        if((room_file = fopen("room-info.txt", "a")) == NULL) {
                perror("Failed to open file.");
                exit(-1);
        }

        // Split command data into separate strings ready to assign as room struct members
        strtok(buffer, " ");
        strcpy(room_name, strtok(NULL, " "));
        capacity = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
        strcpy(password, strtok(NULL, " "));

        // Initialise room struct
        // --Zero write set
        FD_ZERO(&(new_room->write_set));
        // --Set room name
        strcpy(new_room->room_name, room_name);
        // --Set room id
        new_room->room_id = ++natural_id;
        // --Add room to room_list[] and get its index in the array
        for(r_index = 0; r_index < 10000; ++r_index) {
                if(!room_list[r_index]) {
                        room_list[r_index] = new_room;
                        break;
                }
        }

        // Write data to file
        fprintf(room_file, "%s\n", room_name);
        fprintf(room_file, "id=%u\n", natural_id);
        fprintf(room_file, "owner=%s\n", client_list[cli_index]->name);
        fprintf(room_file, "capacity=%d\n", capacity);

        fclose(room_file);

        printf("about to test\n");
        printf("Testing room struct:\n");
        printf("--room name = %s\n", room_list[r_index]->room_name);
        printf("--room id = %u\n", room_list[r_index]->room_id);
        printf("post-test.....................\n");

        // Run new thread as active room
        printf("Starting new room: %s\n", room_name);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void *) &active_room, &r_index);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);


}
```

**Start of new pthread method:**

```
void active_room(void *index) {

        char storage_buffer[BSIZE], output_buffer[BSIZE+32];

        struct timeval timeout;

        int r_index = *(int *) index;

        while(1) {

                // debugging lines.
                printf("1\n");
                printf("room name: %s\n", room_list[r_index]->room_name);
                printf("room id: %u\n", room_list[r_index]->room_id);
                FD_ZERO(&(room_list[r_index]->read_set));
                read_set = write_set;

                timeout.tv_sec = 5;

                printf("2\n");
```

Comment: We need to see more code.  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: `pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void *) &active_room, &r_index);` dont' keep us in suspense. We're not in the business of having to *guess* what `r_index` is, and where it is declared, both of which would be answered before-asked with a proper [mcve]. Likewise for `room_list`. In fact, I highly suspect passing `room_list + r_index` as the thread optional arg, and just using a recoup of that address in your thread proc would solve your problem, but that's pure guessing since I cannot validate it without that [mcve].

Comment: If `r_index` is a local variable in the calling function, it may be destroyed before `active_room()` dereferences the pointer.

Comment: Try printing `r_index` in the caller and the thread function and you may see that they're different.

Comment: Instead of passing `&r_index` to the function, pass `&room_list[r_index]`. That's apparently a global variable, so it will be valid across threads.

Comment: Gotcha. r_index is not a global variable, I have updated it now.

Comment: Don't cast your function pointer to `void*`, provide correct type of function instead. (Change `active_room` accordingly). `pthread_create` does not expect a `void*` pointer anyway. Also there is no warranty that function pointers can be converted to `void*` safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `r_index` variable in `create_new_room` is local to the function.  You then pass its address to `pthread_create` so the thread can use it, but then `create_new_room` exits, causing the lifetime of `r_index` to end.  Then when the thread tried to dereference its argument, it is pointing to memory that is no longer valid, triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You'll need to dynamically allocate memory for the thread's argument so it survives after `create_new_room` exits:

```
int *r_index_arg = malloc(sizeof *r_index_arg);
*r_index_arg = r_index;
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void *) &active_room, r_index_arg);
```

Then you need to make sure you `free` the memory in the thread:

```
int r_index = *(int *) index;
free(index);
```